# Check if the feature gate is enabled /disabled in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, volume, mount, kubelet, kube-apiserver

In Kubernetes , is there a particular way I can check if a specific feature-gate is enabled/disabled. Say, I want to check if MountPropagation feature is enabled in my cluster. How do I do that.

Answer (score 5):

Check [official documents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) for default value, and run `ps aux | grep apiserver | grep feature-gates` on `master` to check if you turn on/off that feature.

Answer (score 5):

- 05/21/2018: Solution #1. This particular approach does not work at the moment. It is outdated in other worlds.
- 06/23/2021: Solution #2. The user can query the system using one or two commands. This is merely an updated solution.

### One Command

```
#Use "kubectl api-resources" for a complete list of supported resources.
[user1@aqua ~]$ kubectl api-resources
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
bindings                                       v1                                     true         Binding
componentstatuses                 cs           v1                                     false        ComponentStatus
configmaps                        cm           v1                                     true         ConfigMap
endpoints                         ep           v1                                     true         Endpoints
events                            ev           v1                                     true         Event
limitranges                       limits       v1                                     true         LimitRange
namespaces                        ns           v1                                     false        Namespace
nodes                             no           v1                                     false        Node
persistentvolumeclaims            pvc          v1                                     true         PersistentVolumeClaim
persistentvolumes                 pv           v1                                     false        PersistentVolume
pods                              po           v1                                     true         Pod
podtemplates                                   v1                                     true         PodTemplate
replicationcontrollers            rc           v1                                     true         ReplicationController
resourcequotas                    quota        v1                                     true         ResourceQuota
secrets                                        v1                                     true         Secret
serviceaccounts                   sa           v1                                     true         ServiceAccount
services                          svc          v1                                     true         Service
mutatingwebhookconfigurations                  admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1        false        MutatingWebhookConfiguration
validatingwebhookconfigurations                admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1        false        ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
customresourcedefinitions         crd,crds     apiextensions.k8s.io/v1                false        CustomResourceDefinition
apiservices                                    apiregistration.k8s.io/v1              false        APIService
controllerrevisions                            apps/v1                                true         ControllerRevision
daemonsets                        ds           apps/v1                                true         DaemonSet
deployments                       deploy       apps/v1                                true         Deployment
replicasets                       rs           apps/v1                                true         ReplicaSet
statefulsets                      sts          apps/v1                                true         StatefulSet
tokenreviews                                   authentication.k8s.io/v1               false        TokenReview
localsubjectaccessreviews                      authorization.k8s.io/v1                true         LocalSubjectAccessReview
selfsubjectaccessreviews                       authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SelfSubjectAccessReview
selfsubjectrulesreviews                        authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SelfSubjectRulesReview
subjectaccessreviews                           authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SubjectAccessReview
horizontalpodautoscalers          hpa          autoscaling/v1                         true         HorizontalPodAutoscaler
cronjobs                          cj           batch/v1                               true         CronJob
jobs                                           batch/v1                               true         Job
certificatesigningrequests        csr          certificates.k8s.io/v1                 false        CertificateSigningRequest
leases                                         coordination.k8s.io/v1                 true         Lease
bgpconfigurations                              crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        BGPConfiguration
bgppeers                                       crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        BGPPeer
blockaffinities                                crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        BlockAffinity
clusterinformations                            crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        ClusterInformation
felixconfigurations                            crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        FelixConfiguration
globalnetworkpolicies                          crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        GlobalNetworkPolicy
globalnetworksets                              crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        GlobalNetworkSet
hostendpoints                                  crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        HostEndpoint
ipamblocks                                     crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPAMBlock
ipamconfigs                                    crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPAMConfig
ipamhandles                                    crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPAMHandle
ippools                                        crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPPool
networkpolicies                                crd.projectcalico.org/v1               true         NetworkPolicy
networksets                                    crd.projectcalico.org/v1               true         NetworkSet
endpointslices                                 discovery.k8s.io/v1                    true         EndpointSlice
events                            ev           events.k8s.io/v1                       true         Event
ingresses                         ing          extensions/v1beta1                     true         Ingress
flowschemas                                    flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta1   false        FlowSchema
prioritylevelconfigurations                    flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta1   false        PriorityLevelConfiguration
nodes                                          metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1                 false        NodeMetrics
pods                                           metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1                 true         PodMetrics
ingressclasses                                 networking.k8s.io/v1                   false        IngressClass
ingresses                         ing          networking.k8s.io/v1                   true         Ingress
networkpolicies                   netpol       networking.k8s.io/v1                   true         NetworkPolicy
runtimeclasses                                 node.k8s.io/v1                         false        RuntimeClass
poddisruptionbudgets              pdb          policy/v1                              true         PodDisruptionBudget
podsecuritypolicies               psp          policy/v1beta1                         false        PodSecurityPolicy
clusterrolebindings                            rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           false        ClusterRoleBinding
clusterroles                                   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           false        ClusterRole
rolebindings                                   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           true         RoleBinding
roles                                          rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           true         Role
priorityclasses                   pc           scheduling.k8s.io/v1                   false        PriorityClass
csidrivers                                     storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        CSIDriver
csinodes                                       storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        CSINode
csistoragecapacities                           storage.k8s.io/v1beta1                 true         CSIStorageCapacity
storageclasses                    sc           storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        StorageClass
volumeattachments                              storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        VolumeAttachment
```

### Two Commands `Kubectl + grep`

```
#Use "kubectl api-resources" for a complete list of supported resources.
[user1@aqua ~]$ kubectl api-resources | grep "PriorityLevelConfiguration"
prioritylevelconfigurations                    flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta1   false        PriorityLevelConfiguration
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to check this on a RKE2 cluster like this:

```
kubectl describe pod/kube-apiserver-<node_name> --namespace kube-system
```

Then I looked at the `Command:` field.

For example, I saw `--feature-gates=RemoveSelfLink=false`

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes [Mount propagation](https://medium.com/kokster/kubernetes-mount-propagation-5306c36a4a2d) allows sharing volumes mounted by a Container with other Containers in the same Pod, or even with other Pods on the same node.

[The Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) does not provide information about feature gates enabled by the command line. It is hard to get these parameters - the only way is to
grep list of the executed process (ps aux) or dig in the /proc filesystem.